# Xtensor return indicies where value is NaN

Tags: indexing, nan, xtensor

Suppose I have a tensor:

```
xt::xtensor_fixed<float, xt::xshape<1, 4>, xt::layout_type::column_major> withnans =
 { {3, std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(), 4, std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()} };
```

i.e. {{3, nan, 4, nan}}

And I wanted to return the positions (indexes) of where there is a nan.

> > {1, 3}

How would I do this in xtensor?

Comment: I think that the questions (and answers) are more readable without overwriting the default layout, or `xtensor_fixed` for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind.

```
xt::xtensor_fixed<float, xt::xshape<1, 4>, xt::layout_type::column_major> withnans =
 { {3, std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(), 4, std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()} };

std::cout << xt::flatten_indices(xt::argwhere(xt::isnan(xt::flatten(withnans)))) << std::endl;
```

> > > {3}